# Why Internet Explorer can not display an image on the site?

Tags: internet-explorer, image

I have a site that is managed with Joomla. I want to display an image in one of my articles but that image can not be viewed in Internet Explorer but other browsers can display it, although the path is ok. Am I missing something?

Link:
    http://ascorbrasov.ro/images/stories/necula_ctin2.jpg

Html:

```
<img src="/images/stories/constantin_necula2.jpg" border="0" 
     title="Constantin Necula - Conferinta" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML code you use to display this image?

Comment: @Philippe: tried right now in IE in a XP VM, the image does not display even when you try to load http://ascorbrasov.ro/images/stories/necula_ctin2.jpg directly.
In all other browser I tried image is fine.

Comment: the image is not rendering in IE but it works in Chrome and FF. You should check the MS support link I gave you in my answer, it could help to verify your image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you didn't use the CMYK colorspace when creating the image, which IE can't handle. Saving it in RGB colorspace should fix the problem (for example, in Adobe Photoshop, use the "Save for web..." option).

I tried resaving the image in GIMP, and it indeed works now in IE for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click on your image and check for encoding and URL.

Try copy/pasting URL of image in address bar and see if the image is rendering.

If it still doesn't work :

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/30770.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283807

You could also try to open your image in an image editor (Paint.NET is free) and save it back to disk. It could work.

Good luck!